# How does cardinality work in an ER diagram when considering the dimension of time?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, cardinality

I will going to explain my question using the fragment of a problem in which there are two entities:

Airplane

Location

And a relationship to link these entities:

Send

**Logic 1:**

An airplane send minimum 1 location and at the most it sends many locations ***(in different moments)***, therefore, the cardinality is one to many (1,N).

```
Airplane ——— (1,N) ——— Send ——— (1,N) ——— Location
```

**Logic 2:**

An airplane send minimum 1 location but it CAN’T send many locations ***at the same time***, therefore, the minimum is 1 and also the maximum is 1, so the cardinality is one to one (1,1).

```
Airplane ——— (1,N) ——— Send ——— (1,1) ——— Location
```

Not only in the ER, but also in a database. Which of these logics is correct?

Comment: Your Question is greatly complicated by the issue of time. So I edited the title to note this.

Comment: @BasilBourque oh thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Many-to-Many

Your business problem may not be clear, so let's look at the canonical example of books and authors. One book can have multiple authors, and each author can potentially contribute to multiple books. So we have a classic Many-to-Many.

A relational database does not handle a many-to-many relationship directly. To do so we add a third table bridging the original two. Naming this third table can be something of a puzzle as it often represents a not-so-concrete business relationship. In this case `authorship` is appropriate.

## Books & Authors

> [book]-1-----0-1-M-[authorship]-M-1-0------1-[author]

Tables:

- `book`

  - `pkey` (primary key, the unique identifier of each book)
  - `title`
  - `planned_publish_date`
- `authorship`

  - `pkey` (optional, as some folks use the other two columns in a combined key as the primary key for this table)
  - `fkey_book`  (holds the primary key value of the book on which this author is contributing)
  - `fkey_author` (holds the primary key value of author who is contributing to this book)
- `author`

  - `pkey`  (primary key, unique identifier of each author)
  - `name`
  - `phone_number`

The cardinality here is:

- A book can have any number of `authorship` rows related: cardinality of 0, 1, M (`M` meaning more than one).

  - A planned book can have zero rows in `authorship` because it is not yet associated with any author. Later, when an author is recruited, we add a row to authorship.
  - A book with a solo author has one `authorship` row, linking to the one author.
  - A book with a pair of authors will have two `authorship` rows, each with a foreign key linking to the `author` row.
- Ditto for the `author`-`authorship` relationship: cardinality of 0, 1, M.

  - An author who has been recruited but not yet committed to any book will have a row in `author` table but no rows in `authorship`.
  - An author who has worked on only a single book will have one row in `authorship`.
  - An prolific author will have many rows in `authorship`, one row for each book on which he/she has contributed.
- An `authorship` row must be assigned to a book AND assigned to an author: cardinality of 1 with `book`, and 1 with `author`.

  - We do not allow any `authorship` rows to be “orphaned”, to use the parent-child language some folks like me use in describing table relationships. In other words, on every `authorship` row, the `pkey_book` field must have a valid value, and the `pkey_author` field must have a valid value.

## Time

Adding the dimension of time is something of a tricky problem.

One example… To track the period of time when each author's contract for a book starts and stops, we would add pair of `DATE` columns on the `authorship` table, titled `contract_start` & `contract_stop`.

- `authorship`

  - `pkey` (primary key for this table)
  - `fkey_book`  (holds the primary key value of the book on which this author is contributing)
  - `fkey_author` (holds the primary key value of author who is contributing to this book)
  - `contract_start` (of type `DATE`)
  - `contract_stop`

A query for *contracts currently in effect* would compare today’s date as being greater-than-or-equal to `contract_start` AND less-than `contract_stop`. Then do a [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) to get title of book and name of author.

Another example… If our publishing company has a business policy that an author must focus on a single book at a time, and wants the database to enforce that an author's contract cannot overlap… well, that is another problem. I'll not address it for a few reasons, one of which is I do not know if your Question has this issue or not.

## Plane-Flight-Location

As for your airplane problem, I am guessing that by `Send` you mean a flight. If so, I would name the table `flight` for clarity. By location, I suppose you mean airport. Again, I would name the table `airport` for clarity.

If this is what you meant, then you have the very same cardinality as discussed above.

- A plane joining the fleet may have never flown yet, has flown once, or has flown to many locations. So, 0-1-M.
- An airport may become known to our system before we have flown any planes there, so zero flight rows. Later, one or more flight rows as we schedule one or more planes to that airport. So, 0-1-M.

The `flight` table has columns for date-time of departure and for duration.

- `flight`

  - `pkey` (primary key for this table)
  - `fkey_plane`  (holds the primary key value of the plane to be flown to this airport at this date-time)
  - `fkey_airport` (holds the primary key value of the airport to which this plane is departing at this date-time.)
  - `departure` (when this flight takes off, of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`)
  - `duration` (the length of this flight, a number of minutes).

> [plane]-1-----0-1-M-[flight]-M-1-0------1-[airport]

Your business rules may vary. If you plan a flight but have not yet assigned an airplane, then we can have a `flight` row without an assigned airplane. So the cardinality of `1` changes to `0 or 1`. But not `M`, as one particular flight never involves multiple planes. In the case of this business rule, a `flight` row can be orphaned, lacking a `plane` parent until eventually when a particular plane is assigned.

> [plane]-1-0-----0-1-M-[flight]-M-1-0------1-[airport]

Comment: Your answer is very explanatory and clear, thank you very much!